# R: apply to matrix margins indices

Tags: r

I have matrix `m`:

```
m = matrix(nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

and some function `f`:

```
f = function(row_index, col_index) {row_index + col_index}
```

How to apply `f` to all row and col *indices*? If I do [apply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html):

```
apply(m, c(1,2), f)
```

then `f` is invoked with the values of `m` (`NA`) and I want it to  be invoked with the indices (1,2 for col and 1,2,3 for row). With this example I should get:

```
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

**Background:**

I want to compare all pairwise combinations of elements of two lists, so my function would look more less like this:

```
f = function(row, col) {
  length(setdiff(list_a[[col]], list_b[[row]]))
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to apply to all rows and columns, or column-wise? If latter, use `MARGIN = 1`. Then, `row_index` and `col_index` will be first and second element in your matrix, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function is vectorized, you can use `row` and `col`.

```
f(row(m), col(m))
# For this example, you can also use:
row(m) + col(m)
# [1,]    2    3
# [2,]    3    4
# [3,]    4    5
```

If it is not vectorized, you can vectorize it with `Vectorize`,
but you end up with a vector, rather than a matrix:
you need to reshape the result.

```
g <- Vectorize(f)
matrix( g(row(m), col(m)), nr=nrow(m) )
```